# Pass package name as a variable

Tags: python, import, conda

I would like to pass package name as a variable in jupyter notebook and then install those packages by conda in jupyter. 
I have prepared the following code but it is not working. 
I think that "i" does not recognize as numpy in "!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} i".
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import sys
import importlib
a=['numpy','itertools','wxPython']
for i in a:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(i)
        print('%s is imported'%i)
    except ImportError:
        !conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} i
        importlib.import_module(i)
        print('%s was successfully imported'%i)
```

This produces:

```
Error:  
------------
Solving environment: ...working... failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - i
------------------------------------------
```

From my point of view, it wants to install a package called "i" and since such a package is not available, it returns the above error. I am wondering why it is not able to consider "i" equal to 'numpy' in the line "!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} i". The reason is that when I tried "!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} 'numpy' ", there was no error.

Comment: As far as I know, for import you should use `import wx`. And for installation `conda install wxpython`. So I think you have to create two lists, one for installation and another for import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to mark `i` as a variable you need to enclose it in curly braces.
Here is a simple example of how that works:

```
a = 'foo'
!echo a
!echo {a}
```

Produces:

```
a
foo
```

For your particular case it would look a bit like this:

```
import sys

a=['numpy','itertools','wxPython']
for i in a:
    try:
        exec('import %s' % i)
        print('%s is imported'%i)
    except ImportError:
        !conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} {i}
        exec('import %s' % i)
        print('%s was successfully imported'%i)
```

Note that I switched out the importlib call for a line with exec so that the modules are assigned to the namespace. There is probably a more pythonic way to do this if you are more familiar with importlib.

This does not fully resolve the issue for me, as I continue to get `ModuleNotFoundError`s for wxPython, but it does resolve your immediate error.

Comment: @mahdi Did you have trouble with the ModuleNotFoundErrors, or are they specific to my machine?

Comment: Yes, I do have a problem. You have any idea why it bring such an error

Comment: @mahdi I would guess that they are related to either the configuration of conda on our machines, or that they are due to an error specific to the package. If you are able to install other packages with conda, then the problem would be with the package. I don't know too much about debugging either type of error, and they are probably a separate question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `__import__` function to dynamically import a module. You need to assign this to a variable.

```
mod = 'time'
time = __import__(mod)
time.sleep(5)
```

You can assign the list of imported packages to a dict.

Comment: The problem is also installing not just importing. with your command, I can import any module comes in the string as I have had it in my code.